# Error when add two pattern to ng-patterns in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, regex

I tried below code to add validation to both MAC and IP addresses.

[image]

Comment: Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

Comment: I don't think you need to close each regex expression before combining them. Try replacing `/ | /` with `|` in between

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control with-primary-addon" placeholder="Calling Station ID" aria-describedby="idadd" id="idid" minlength="7"  maxlength="45" name="callingId" ng-model="vm.trafficDataInfo.callingId" ng-pattern='/([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}) | ([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})$/'>